# Regression alternatives for proportional data that do not rely on the 0 - 1 interval

Tags: regression, proportion, beta-distribution, percentage

I'm currently analyzing data consisting of change in cognitive performance and how it is related with a physiological variable (enzymatic activity) in a group of people.

As all people were assessed in two periods, I need to analyze the raw data of the deltas (time 2 - time 1) for all variables. In this sense, for example if one person have a performance of 14 in time1 and 8 in time 2, negative values (8-14) would imply worse performance in this person/test.

Furthermore, to compare (and summarize) among test, I transform the delta values to "percentage of change" using the value from time1 as the 100%. At the end I have a model like this, which includes besides the enzymatic activity, some covariables like gender, age and alcohol consumption:

%change.test ~ % change_enzyme.act. + age + gender + study.yrs + alcohol(gr)

Here are some data: perc.ChE is the change (percentage of) in ezymatic activity, and perc.EM1, perc.Mem1, perc.Mem2 and perc.Mem3 describe the change (percentage of) in cognitive tests.

`..gender age study.yrs  alc.g perc.ChE perc.EM1 perc.Mem1 perc.Mem2 perc.Mem3
1  female  30        17   3.20    67.40     0.00     40.00     50.00      0.00
2    male  38         8   5.09     2.58     0.00     28.57      0.00     33.33
3  female  20        12   4.80    63.84     0.00     14.29     12.50      0.00
4    male  19        12 106.51    16.17     7.41    -20.00      0.00      0.00
5  female  41        12   0.00   -18.88     7.14    -10.00    -10.00      0.00
6  female  42         7   0.00    19.94     0.00    -42.86    -28.57     25.00
7    male  44        12   0.00    -8.32     0.00      0.00    -18.18      0.00
8  female  30        17   0.69   -19.55    -3.33     25.00      0.00     50.00
9  female  36        14   0.00   -28.86     0.00      0.00      0.00    -33.33
10 female  25        14   0.00    -7.00     0.00     20.00    -20.00    -20.00
11 female  45        12     NA    13.07     3.45     40.00      0.00    -20.00
12 female  36        15   0.00   -38.86     7.41    -18.18    -16.67      0.00
13 female  48         8     NA    -8.82     8.00     40.00     14.29     20.00
14 female  49        14   0.27    -5.23     7.14     44.44      0.00     25.00
15 female  37        12   1.60     9.22     0.00     11.11      0.00      0.00
16 female  49         6   0.00   180.76     3.70     40.00    -14.29      0.00
17   male  29        12   0.00   -13.93     7.41     20.00     60.00    -16.67
18 female  43        14   2.18    -7.38    -3.45     85.71    240.00    -20.00
19 female  29        12   3.43   -21.46    -6.67    -25.00    -40.00    -33.33
20   male  46         8     NA    -9.93    -6.90      0.00    -22.22      0.00`
 ---

As you can see, despite the variables starting with "perc." are percentages, since some people perform worse in the second cognitive test, there are negative values. Similarly, since some enzymatic activities were lower the second time, there are also negative percentages there. Notice that it can be also improvements (positive percentages) higher than 100% (for example when the improvement (delta t2 - t1) is beyond the total score of time 1):

As far I've checked, proportions that came from continuous variables should be analyzed with Beta regression, however, since that method restrict response variables (the cognitive tests) to be in the 0-1 interval I'm not sure how to continue.

Can someone help me here to know how to proceed? For me "negative proportions" are informative since they tell us that people reduce their performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A "percentage of change" is a *ratio,* but it is not a *proportion.*  The latter is a part of a whole, expressed as a fraction of that whole, and therefore must lie between 0 and 1. (Also it is not the case that proportions should be analyzed with Beta regression; indeed, in many cases Beta regression would be inappropriate.) Usually, differences and ratios are difficult to model, so if it's possible to model the *original terms* that are being compared, you can achieve better statistical performance and greater insight.

Comment: To add-on to @whuber, depending on the types of changes you observe, often it makes sense to use log(T2/T1). It almost never makes sense to use "% change".

Comment: Thanks for your fast responses!!